# Trying to make a login with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a login with CodeIgniter for what I followed a tutorial I found because I had little clue how to do it.

So I have a login model, view and controller and a verifylogin controller as well. The problem is that it always validates the form as an invalid login, I don't know why:

**Login Controller**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Acceso no autorizado');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $datos = array(
            'home_name' => $this->config->item('home_name'),
            'root_path' => $this->config->item('root_path')
        );

        $this->load->helper('form');

        // Menú principal
        $this->load->view('menu', $datos);

        // TODO: Put your code here...
        $this->load->view('login', $datos);

        // Cierre html
        $this->load->view('cierre', $datos);
    }
}
?>
```

**Login View**

```
<div id='content-login'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id='logo' class='login buscadores'>
            <span class='icon icon-lock'></span>
            <h1>Inicia sesión</h1>
            <p>Accede como usuario a <?php echo $home_name?></p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div id='buscadores' class='container'>
                <div class='content'>
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <?php echo form_open('verifylogin');
                        $datos = array(
                                'name' => 'username',
                                'placeholder' => 'Usuario',
                                'class' => 'text',
                                'size' => '25'
                            );
                        echo form_input($datos);

                        $datos = array(
                                'name' => 'password',
                                'placeholder' => 'Contraseña',
                                'class' => 'text',
                                'size' => '25'
                            );
                        echo form_password($datos);

                        $datos = array(
                                    'id' => 'login',
                                    'name' => 'login',
                                    'value' => 'Login',
                                    'class' => 'button cursor'
                                );
                        echo form_submit($datos);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Login Model**

```
<?php 
class User extends CI_Model
{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('id, username, password');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? $query->result() : false;
    }
}
```

**VerifyLogin Controller**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Acceso no autorizado');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user', '', TRUE);
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Usuario', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Contraseña', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            /*$datos = array(
                'home_name' => $this->config->item('home_name'),
                'root_path' => $this->config->item('root_path')
            );

            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->view('menu', $datos);
            $this->load->view('login', $datos);
            $this->load->view('cierre', $datos);*/
            echo "error en login"; // IT ALWAYS ENDS UP HERE........
        }
        else
        {   echo "login correcto"; // NEVER HERE
            //redirect('portada', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function check_database($password)
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

        if ($result)
        {
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $sess_array = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'username' => $row->username
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Funny thing, my friend is running the exact same web in localhost and for him it works but it doesn't for me. Actually he got an error that I didn't get and just loading the session library in the verifylogin controller construct it went away and works perfectly...

Comment: If it's working for him and not you, it could be a database configuration issue. Have you checked your logs to see if anything is jumping out?

Comment: I exported my sql and he imported it on his database, it's exactly the same data.

Comment: ok cool. Now, while I'm trying to figure out another answer, here's an "is it plugged in" question. Does the DB user you're connecting with have "select" grants on the table?

Comment: yes, I am connected as root actually.

Comment: okidoki, just making sure.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. The apache module rewrite needed to be active but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're ever letting codeigniter grab your password in the first place because you're missing a helper import (granted I would think this would throw an error of some sort so check your logs)

Also, you could be loading this helper in your **autoload.php** config

Use this in your verify controller

`$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`

All the docs assume the same controller and function for validation (which makes a lot of sense when you think about it, so long as you don't write 20 lines of code to handle things and separate out into discrete bits of functionality)

Comment: what do you mean? $password is the argument of the function check_database.

Comment: Check out my comment on my main post.

Comment: Absolutely! I'll get right on it. We'll get to the bottom of this. Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: I added that to my controller and I still has the same problem. Anyway, read my first comment in response to my main post, I am still looking for a solution for that weird issue unsuccessfully.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep looking at it throughout the day unless you figure something out. If you want to take this to chat we can

Comment: I never used chat, as you can see I'm new to stackoverflow but it'd be a greatly appreciated help, so yeah, let's take this to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43218/discussion-between-zarazthuztra-and-kpagcha)